# Connecting progress value and <div> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a progress bar.

And I want to create a speech bubble that follows the value.

This is sample.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDEyE.png)

Here is my code

```css
 body{display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 100vh;}
        progress{ width: 1200px; accent-color: white; background: white; height: 30px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
        progress[value] {-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none;}
        progress::-moz-progress{ width: 1200px; accent-color: white; background: white; height: 30px;}
        progress::-moz-progress-bar {border-radius: 100px; background: #f9f0f2; background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,255,255), rgba(249, 102, 129, 0.1));}
        progress::-webkit-progress-bar {background: #f9f0f2;border-radius: 100px; position: relative;}
        progress::-webkit-progress-bar::after{position: absolute; content: ""; }
        progress::-webkit-progress-value {border-radius: 100px;background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(254, 212, 220), rgba(249, 102, 129, 1)); position: relative;}
        progress::-webkit-progress-value::after{position: absolute; content: ""; font-size: 1000px;}
        progress::-moz-progress-value {border-radius: 100px;background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(254, 212, 220), rgba(249, 102, 129, 1));}
        .barText { width: 279px; margin: 50px auto; border-radius: 60px; background: #f9f0f2; color: #000; padding: 20px; text-align: center; font-weight: 900; font-family: arial; position: relative; top: -200px; left: 350px;}
        .barText:before {content: ""; width: 0px; height: 0px; position: absolute; border-left: 20px solid #f9f0f2; border-right: 20px solid transparent; border-top: 40px solid #f9f0f2; border-bottom: 40px solid transparent; left: 10px; top: 30px; transform: rotate(22deg);}
```

```html
    <progress value="50" max="100" class="progressBar"></progress>
    <div class="barText"></div>
```

In my opinion, position is problem.

How can solve this problem?

Comment: Hi, can you tell us about what you have tried already?

Comment: Put both the progress element and the . barText into an additional container element. Remove absolute positioning from progress, apply it to the new container element instead, if you need to center the whole thing (otherwise, just make the container `relative`.) And then just position .barText _absolute_, with a `left` coordinate that matches your current progress state, i.e. full width * percentage.